# Search in Related Model using GridView Filter Field

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

**Question:**
  Let's Say i have two tables,

```
Table1            Table2
-authorId         -username
```

As of now my sql query on search model looks like this,

```
->andFilterWhere(['"Table1"."authorId"' => $this->authorName]);
```

It only helps to search and filter using the authorID.

**Expected Result**
  I would like to search based on the authorname instead of authorId.

---

I faced similar difficulty in reflecting data in view but i was able to fix it with following getter function in base model.

```
public function getAuthorName() {
        return $this->author->username;
    }
```

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a custom attribute to your search model

```
public $username
```

define a relation to your `author` table inside the model

```
public function getAuthor() {
        return $this->hasOne(Author::className(),['id'=>'authorId']);
    }
```

in your `gridview` replace the `authorId` column with

```
`author.username`
```

and use the following to compare

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', '{{%Table2}}.username',$this->username]);
```

and yes make sure you join you searchmodel query with the `author` table in the start of search function

```
->joinWith('author')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `authorId` is a FK to `table2`, and you have previoulsy joined `table2` to `table1`, you can do the following:

```
->andFilterWhere(['table2.username' => $this->authorName]);
```

Comment: Tried this, But ended up with following error while search and filter.
Adding the error as answer since it's too large.