# Yii2: filterModel's GridView "must be an integer" error

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have a model called **Holidays** and a model called **Persons**.

**Holidays** has the fields: **holiday_id** and **person_id**.

**Persons** has the fields: **person_id** and **person_name**.

Then I have a [GridView widget](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-gridview) to show the **Holidays** model:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'person_id',
            'label' => 'Person',
            'value' => function($model) {
                $persons = \app\models\Persons::findOne(['person_id' => $model->person_id]);
                return $persons->person_name;
            }
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

But the filter is not working because it wants to search by person_id. **I need to search by person_name.** It shows the error "Persons must be an integer".

[image: GridView Widget showing error: "Persons must be an integer".]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search in Related Model using GridView Filter Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48418082/search-in-related-model-using-gridview-filter-field)

Answer (score 0):

your grid is trying to filter by `person_id`, you need update your search model to filter by related data. (since person_name is not a property of holiday model)

Follow [this guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview) in the official docs